# MVC Persist Model per Browser Tab

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model, tabs, persist

I have an MVC app and I've run into a problem with modern multitab browsers.

I have a screen that creates a model and stores it in this.TempData["MyViewModel"]

I then open the same screen in a 2nd tab and as it calls the same controller methods this.TempData["MyViewModel"] is once again set.

If I then go back to Tab 1 and refresh the page, I am presented with the data I entered in Tab 2.

Is there a way to store data in TempData uniquely per browser tab ?

I have toyed with the idea of creating a unique TempData key and persist it between requests using either the querystring or a hidden field but this seems messy.

Any ideas / advice would be most welcome. :o)

---

What I have so far is a concept of a 'ProcessID'.

In my first partial view I have a form with a hidden field which is loosely bound to my Model.ProcessID.  When the form is posted this hidden field ProcessID is used as the TempData key...

Example:

```
public sealed class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        this.ProcessID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public string ProcessId { get; set; }
    // other fields
}
```

Partial View 1:

```
@model Models.MyViewModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PartialView1", "Home", new { }, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "myDivToUpdate" }, new { }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProcessId);

    // other fields...

    <input type="submit" value="next" />
}

public ActionResult PartialView1(FormCollection form)
{
    return this.PartialView("PartialView1", new Models.MyViewModel());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PartialView1(FormCollection form)
{    
    Models.MyViewModel vm = new Models.MyViewModel();    

    this.UpdateModel(vm, form);

    this.TempData[vm.ProcessId] = vm;

    return this.PartialView("PartialView2", vm);
}
```

In my 2nd partial view form I once again have a hidden field loosely bound to the same Model.ProcessID.  When this form is posted I can use the Model.ProcessID to retrieve my viewmodel from TempData and update it:

Partial View 2:

```
@model Models.MyViewModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PartialView2", "Home", new { }, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "myDivToUpdate" }, new { }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProcessId);

    // other fields (different to partial view 1)...

    <input type="submit" value="finish" />
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PartialView2(FormCollection form, Models.MyViewModel vm)
{
    vm = (this.TempData[vm.ProcessId] as Models.MyViewModel);

    this.UpdateModel(vm, form);

    return this.Json(new { result = true, message = "success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing your model in `Session` BIG NO NO! Just have your tabs situated in a partial view and reload the content via ajax on click? Something like what you can do with jQuery tabs, that way you don't have the headache.

Comment: I'm using TempData which is only persisted for 1 following request after the request that sets it.  I need to persist the viewmodel between a couple of controller requests so this is what TempData is ideal for.  The issue is that TempData like ViewData is a dictionary with a string based key which if hardcoded to a value such as "MyViewModel" will be overwritten by another tab in the browser if that tab is also viewing the same page.  What I need is a TempData store (or the likes) that is unique per tab.

Answer (score 0):

By default I believe MVC uses session state to store TempData using the SessionStateTempDataProvider and therefore each TempData will be stored in the same place for that session. Using session the only around this that I can see is to use some identifier as you suggested.

However you can implement the ITempDataProvider interface to use your own provider that could then store this data in some other form of storage (such as cookies or sql).